Etherscan Approval Query
I swapped USDT for a token in dextools & Etherscan shows the transaction as successful but the token has not imported & the usdt funds are still in my wallet. When I go to approval & connect my wallet there is a Reset button & a USD amount at risk. Will the transaction complete if I press Reset?

Would need more info. Though sounds like first transaction was an approval for a contract to move the token being sold, and you would need a second to execute the swap.
